# jQuery: Проверка на существование вложенных элементов

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Распродажа</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Кухни</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Кухни ДСП</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Кухни массив дуба</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Кухни акрил</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Кухни массив ясеня</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Кухни крашение</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Гостиные</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Детские</a></li>
</ul>
```

-

```
function initMenu() {
    $('.menu ul').hide();
    $('.menu li.current').parent().show();
    $('.menu li').bind('click',function() {
        $(this).children('ul').slideToggle(300);
        return false;
    });
}
$(initMenu);
```

Задача - сделать так, чтобы если нету в li еще одного ul, то ссылка остается ссылкой. Если точнее, то Распродажа, Гостиные, Детские - просто ссылки, а Кухни - выпадающее меню. Вот как return false назначить только для Кухни (в данном случае - Кухни. Вообще для любых пунктов, где нет вложенных ul)?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Ну вы всегда можете проверить, если выбранный элемент вообще и если есть, то сколько их, узнав длину массива. Например,

    if (!$(selector).length) {
        // нет таких элементов
    }

Если я не правильно понял вопрос, извините)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я нашел человеческий вариант - .has()

```
$(function(){
    $('.menu ul').hide();
    $('.menu li.current').parent().show();
    $('.menu li').has('ul').bind('click',function(){
        $(this).children('ul').slideToggle(300);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Только правильней будет эвент вешать на тег "a". Как там принято говорить - ИМХО.

Comment: @VasyOk А вот не факт, что у нас там ссылка будет.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
    $('ul.menu>li>a').on('click', function(e) {
        if ($(this).parent().find('ul').length > 0) {
            e.preventDefault();
            /* тут код по раскрытию меню, или другим действиям */
        }
    });
});
```

или (должно работать для любого списка-меню, с разными вложеностями, но лучше опираться на класс)

```
$(function(){
    $('ul li>a').on('click', function(e) {
        if ($(this).parent().find('ul').length > 0) {
            e.preventDefault();
            /* тут код по раскрытию меню, или другим действиям */
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: [.siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) 

    $(this).parent().find('ul')
    // == 
    $(this).siblings('ul')

Comment: Спасибо не знал.

Answer (score 0):

А зачем это нужно? Хотите сделать раскрывающееся меню? Тогда делать лучше так. Все делаете ссылками. Вложенные списки прячете через nav ul ul{display:none}. И код:

```
$('nav').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    var $submenu = $(this).closest('li').find('ul').eq(0);

    if($submenu.length){
        e.preventDefault();
        $submenu.toggle();
    }
});
```

Т.е. применяем делегирование. Если есть вложенные список то дефолтное действие ссылки отменяется и раскрывается список, если нет списка то переход по ссылке.